# Growing a div in width on hover with css with text

Tags: html, css

I have a div with text inside a `<p>` and I want to create a slide effect on the text using only css. To do this, I am trying to set the `<p>` to `width:0px;` and change it to 100% when I hover over the div. Except that when I set the width to 0, the text inside won't stay where it was. Is  there a way to get around this?
Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dyy1hm57/), and a snippet below.

```css
html,body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
#block {
  width: 23%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center
}
#block p {
  width: 0px;
  transition: all .5s linear;
  background-color: red;
}
#block:hover p {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
<p>
Text Text Text
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: After the user has hovered over the div, would you like the text to stay centered and `<p>` still at 100% width?

Comment: Yes that's what I would like.

Answer (score 3):

i updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dyy1hm57/2/)

```
#block p {
  width: 0px;
  transition: all .5s linear;
  background-color: red;
  /* added css */
  overflow:hidden; 
  white-space:nowrap; 
  /* added css */
}
```

is this what you want to happen?

Comment: To be a "good" answer you should explain what makes yours work and the OP's doesn't; what's different, what did you fix, _why_ does it work.

Comment: That's pretty much what I want but, suppose there's a lot of text inside and I need it to wrap inside the borders of the outside div, is there a way to accommodate for that?

Comment: @VanillaLore you could remove the fixed height on your `#block` div and remove the `white-space:nowrap; ` on `#block p` but it would look like this http://jsfiddle.net/dyy1hm57/3/

Comment: @VanillaLore here's a [couple more twiddles](http://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/dyy1hm57/4/) to GvM's changes that behave slightly differently, but one issue is that while the `<p>` is transitioning from 0 width to 100% it will change heights as wrapping changes. You can see the box grow in height then shrink again. For a brief time it will be wrapped with one word-per-line, giving it a lot of height. You may want to change its _position_ rather than its _width_ (using `position:relative`)

Comment: @StephenP Changing it's position rather than its width turned out to be the best option. Thank you all very much for the help.